# configure the jest moduleNameMapper not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocking, jestjs

I want to apply a jest test to react component and I get an error that says:

> Jest encountered an unexpected token

When I try to:

```
import moment from 'moment';
import './style.css';   //<----here
```

I try to mock css files and image objects and change the configuration:

```
// package.json
{
"jest": {
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
  "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
}
}
}
```

My styleMock.js is:

```
module.exports = {};
```

My fileMock.js is:

```
module.exports = 'test-file-stub';
```

But I still get the error:

> Jest encountered an unexpected token

and the error is in the same place as it was previously.

My jest is the latest version "24.8.0".

Anyone knows why?